# Using Collectors.toMap to return a LinkedHashMap

Tags: java, linkedhashmap, collectors

How can I convert this:

```
return this.subjects.entrySet()
            .stream()
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(e -> getArtistryCopy(e.getKey()), Map.Entry::getValue));
```

To return a LinkedHashMap instead of a map?

If you need to know, `this.subjects` is a `LinkedHashMap<AbstractArtistries, ArrayList<AbstractCommand>>`. AbstractArtistry and command are two custom objects I made. I need the order to be maintained.

`getArtistryCopy()` returns a copy of an AbstractArtistry (which is the key).

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can use [the overload of `Collectors.toMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#toMap-java.util.function.Function-java.util.function.Function-java.util.function.BinaryOperator-java.util.function.Supplier-) that accepts a `Supplier` for the `Map`.  It also takes a `merge` function that how to resolve collisions between duplicate keys.

```
return this.subjects.entrySet()
        .stream()
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(e -> getArtistryCopy(e.getKey()), 
                                  Map.Entry::getValue,
                                  (val1, val2) -> yourMergeResultHere,
                                  LinkedHashMap::new));
```

Comment: A simple merge function is just `(a, b) -> b`, which overwrites the previous value, as if by `Map.put`. Since the OP is mapping the keys, though, I think they should probably think about what they actually want to do with a merge. (I think `(a, b) -> b)` might be the behavior people would expect by default, [when actually `toMap(Function, Function)` throws if it encounters a duplicate key](https://ideone.com/DP6e8E).)

Comment: @Radiodef That's reasonable.  For my answer, the merge function was just an afterthought, because the only overload of `toMap` that took a `Supplier` was one that also took a merge function.